# logging in a table like pm2 with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, console

I want to format all of my script's logs into a table for clarity purposes. Kind of what pm2 (process manager 2) does atm for example.

As of today I use `console.table(logs)` where logs is an object of variables I want to keep track of. It works great but I want to get rid of the trailing `\n` that console.table includes.

I would want to do something like: `process.stdout.write(table(logs))` where I don't have to create the table function myself.

I tried to find the source code of `console.table` to copy it and remove the trailing newline as a utils function without success. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The npm package c-log does a wonderful job at this : [npm c-log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-log)

Comment: Thanks, I went with `cli-table` which is a dependency of the package you mentioned as it's maintained and up to date. Thanks for the mention tho!